# I want to make a box like this chat bubble

Tags: tcolorbox

I have typeset some chat app messages, like Facebook or QQ, but iwant some beautiful chat bubbles like this, could someone use tikz or tcolorbox make it
[image: a chat bubble of one chat app]

Comment: This thread may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62086/quotes-with-speech-balloons

Comment: slightly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405132/how-to-make-every-line-in-a-bubble-like-chat-conversations

Comment: If you want symbols at the top, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181059/36296

Comment: these two eyes at the corner may be modified from that link 36296

Comment: thanks a lot for all of you, I have found a method in this repoitory https://github.com/xiaoleeza/WeiChat